# Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CameraController.main'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float main;
    public Transform car;
    public float distance;
    public float height;
    public float rotationDamping;
    public float zoomRatio;
    public float defaultFOV;

    public float rotation_vector;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 local_velocity = car.InverseTransformDirection(car.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity);
        if (local_velocity.z <-0.5f)
        {
            rotation_vector = car.eulerAngles.y;

        }
        else
        {
            rotation_vector = car.eulerAngles.y;
        }

        float accelaration = car.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude;
        CameraController.main.fieldOfView = defaultFOV + accelaration * zoomRatio * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        float wantedAngle = rotation_vector;

        float wantedHeight = car.position.y + height;
        float myAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        float myHeight = transform.position.y;

        myAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(myAngle, wantedAngle, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);
        myHeight = Mathf.LerpAngle(myHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping * Time.deltaTime);

        quaternion currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, myAngle, 0);

        transform.position = car.position;
        transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;

        Vector3 temp = transform.position;
        temp.y = myHeight;
        transform.position = temp;

        transform.LookAt(car);





    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't javascript. It looks like java except the `using` keywords (unless they've been added since I last used Java a few years back).

Comment: You should to remove those garbage characters at the end of your question and explain why searching for this error message on the web did not provide any useful or understandable result instead.

Comment: OK, main is not static, so you wouldnt refer to it as CameraController.main, its just "main" as its local to that instance of the script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language this is. It's definitely not javascript despite the tag you added. It looks like java, except the `using` keywords, `:`, and the styling.

Assuming it's a Java-like language, then the error is telling you to use `this.main` instead of `CameraController.main`. You can only do `<className>.<property>` for static fields. For non-static fields, you need to use `<objectName>` instead of `<classname>`.

That being said, there are other errors in your code; like immediately after, you have `main.fieldOfView` despite that `main` is of type `float`.